# Multitple selection while query for media files

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, mediastore

```
  val selection =
        "${MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION} >= ?" + "${MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM} =?"
    val selectionArgs = arrayOf(
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS).toString(),
        albumData?.albumName
    )
```

due to this code app is crashing at runtime.

I want to retrive media tracks for any particular album. so how can i write selection query also, i want to retrieve track greater than 20 secs.

If i remove duration from selection and selectionArgs then i am getting media tracks but i want to get media only greater than 20 secs.

**Exception**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.knesarcreation.playbeat, PID: 18916
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "album": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT _id, _display_name, duration, _size, album, artist, album_id, _data FROM audio WHERE ((is_pending=0 OR (is_pending=1 AND lower(_data) NOT REGEXP '.*/\.pending-(\d+)-([^/]+)$' AND owner_package_name IN ( 'com.knesarcreation.playbeat' ))) AND (is_trashed=0) AND (volume_name IN ( 'external_primary' , '9016-4ef8' ))) AND (duration >= ?album =?) ORDER BY _display_name ASC
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:186)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:142)
    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:473)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:1190)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:1121)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:1077)
    at com.knesarcreation.playbeat.fragment.AlbumFragment.loadAlbumSongs(AlbumFragment.kt:134)
```

Please help.

Comment: Tell us wich exception lets your app crash. Then catch() it.

Comment: That's not a problem of exception and crashing app .. problem is whether I am writing correct query or not @blackapps

Comment: Apparently not. But to know why examine which exception is thrown.

Comment: you can see the exception

Comment: Yes. An SQLiteException. And why is sqlite throwing that exception? Wel it's telling you : 'syntax error'. Which you did not mention to us too. Log the value of your selection parameter to ... see the select statement.

Comment: yes dude! i know i am writting wrong query . I add the query in question also. I am not sure how to write the query for my expected output

Comment: If you know please help.

Comment: val selection =
            "${MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION} >= ?"
        val selectionArgs = arrayOf(
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS).toString())

Comment: This query is working fine but i dont want this. i want to  include one more condition that media should be greater than 20 secs

Comment: What tag should i add for this question? i think mediaPlayer is a correct tag for this question

Comment: I removed that, now can you please explain how to solve this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236958/discussion-between-kaunain-and-blackapps).

Comment: @blackapps added tag, now please explain

Comment: @forpas you mean.

Comment: @blackapps i made change to your query now its working.. what i changed...             
             val selection =   "${MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION} >= ?" + "AND 
            ${MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM} =?"         Thanks for your answer

Comment: I mistyped Kotlin's string interpolation: `val selection = "${MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION} >= ? AND ${MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM} =?"` There is no need for concatenation.

Comment: but concatenation also working @forpas but i'll remove it now

Comment: actually concatenatig and without concatinating  doing the same work . you are right no need to concatenate in kotlin